# Swift: Separate String into String Array and Append Separator

Tags: swift

How would I split a string to include the separators?

Lets say I had a string such as...

```
let myString = "apple banana orange grapes"
```

If I used

```
let separatedString = myString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
```

my resulting array would be

```
["apple","banana","orange","grapes"]
```

How would I achieve a result of

```
["apple ","banana ","orange ","grapes"]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you have a specific reason for the extra space. If you really need it, you could also add the space later when your array is used.

Comment: @Asdrubal I'd like to keep the spaces because I'd like to keep track of the character count / location of each word from the original string. I also just wanted to avoid using NSRanges

Comment: Would something like this be of interest to you? https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGWordCounter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative using regular expression:

```
let myString = "apple banana orange grapes"
let pattern = "\\w+\\s?"
let regex  = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(myString, options:[], range: NSMakeRange(0, myString.characters.count))
  .map { (myString as NSString).substringWithRange($0.range)}
print(matches) // -> ["apple ", "banana ", "orange ", "grapes"]
```

Comment: from another comment in this thread,

Would there be a way to adjust this answer for if there were multiple component separators? If the accepted separators were " " and "\n", how would you know which to insert?

Comment: @bremmm This regex considers space characters as well as `\t`, `\n`, `\r`. The pattern does: *Catch any alphanumeric character (one or more) followed by an (optional) whitespace character*. There is no *insertion*, the respective whitespace character after the match is included.

Answer (score 2):

`array.map` lets you process the resulting array an add the space back in.

```
let separatedString = myString
  .componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
  .map { "\($0) " }
```

That last line iterates over all strings in the split up array and puts them in `$0`, and returns a new string with the space added back in which gets used as the replacement for the original string.

Comment: Would there be a way to adjust this answer for if there were multiple component separators?

If the accepted separators were " " and "\n", how would you know which to insert?

Comment: Yeah that gets trickier. You'd need multiple passes, or regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Since you updated your question, it looks now you no longer want a new space on the last word.

So here's my updated code

```
let text = "apple banana orange grapes"

let chunks: [String] = text
    .componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    .reverse()
    .enumerate()
    .map { $0.element + ( $0.index == 0 ? "" : " ") }
    .reverse()

print(chunks) // ["apple ", "banana ", "orange ", "grapes"]
```

### Multiple separators

Thank to *@vadian* for the suggestion

```
let text = "apple banana\norange grapes"

let chunks: [String] = text
    .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    .reverse()
    .enumerate()
    .map { $0.element + ( $0.index == 0 ? "" : " ") }
    .reverse()

print(chunks) // ["apple ", "banana ", "orange ", "grapes"]
```

Comment: from another comment of mine in this thread,

Would there be a way to adjust this answer for if there were multiple component separators? If the accepted separators were " " and "\n", how would you know which to insert?

Comment: @bremmm: Please see the __Multiple separators__ section in my answer

Comment: @appzYourLife `componentsSeparatedByCharactersFromSet` with `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` for multiple separators might be more appropriate.

Comment: @vadian: You are totally right. Thank your for the hint!